# Instantiating non-library-level package in SPARK Ada

Tags: ada, spark-ada, spark-2014

How do I instantiate a non-library-level package in SPARK Ada?

Say I have something like:

```
subtype Die is Integer range 1..6;
package Random_Die
is
  new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Die);
```

That gives me the errors:

```
instantiation error at a-nudira.ads.45
incorrect placement of "Spark_Mode"
Random_Die is not a libray level package
```

Presumably I need to turn SPARK_Mode off for Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random, but I can't work out the right place to put the pragma.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are only checked by SPARK when they are instantiated. :-(

The error message looks like you have attempted to put a SPARK_Mode aspect somewhere inside the generic.  That will not work.  You should put the `SPARK_Mode => On` aspect on the unit instantiating the generic package.

Comment: The only mention of SPARK_Mode *I* have is the SPARK_Mode => On on the entire package that contains the code I cited. The error message points to a-nudira.ads.45, which says SPARK_Mode => Off, but a-nudira.ads is a standard library module from the GNAT distribution, not my own code.

Comment: Strange.  Then maybe you should simply do as requested, and make the generic instantiation of `Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random` a library level package.

Answer (score 1):

The message isn't so much about `Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random`. Spark-2014 wants you to make your unnamed package, `Unnamed`, say, to be at library level, like Jacob Sparre Andersen mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44840157/4449975). To wit:

```
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;

--procedure Outer is
   package Unnamed
      with Spark_Mode => On
   is
      subtype Die is Integer range 1..6;
      package Random_Die
      is
        new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Die);
   end Unnamed;
--begin
--   null;
--end Outer;
```

Removing the comments' hyphens and translating `Outer` yields your error message. Translating `Unnamed` as is will work fine, and `gnatprove` has no complaints. In other words, `Unnamed` is then a library level package. Within `Outer` it isn't and this makes GNAT issue the diagnostic message.